# Filling higher-frequency windows when upsampling with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting low-frequency data to a higher frequency with pandas (for instance monthly to daily). When making this conversion, I would like the resulting higher-frequency index to span the entire low-frequency window. For example, suppose I have a monthly series, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
data = np.random.randn(2)
s = Series(data, index=date_range('2012-01-01', periods=len(data), freq='M'))

s
2012-01-31    0
2012-02-29    1
```

Now, I convert it to daily frequency:

```
s.resample('D')
2012-01-31     0
2012-02-01   NaN
2012-02-02   NaN
2012-02-03   NaN
...
2012-02-27   NaN
2012-02-28   NaN
2012-02-29     1
```

Notice how the resulting output goes from 2012-01-31 to 2012-02-29. But what I really want is days from 2011-01-01 to 2012-02-29, so that the daily index "fills" the entire January month, even if 2012-01-31 is still the only non-NaN observation in that month.

I'm also curious if there are built-in methods that give more control over how the higher-frequency period is filled with the lower frequency values. In the monthly to daily example, the default is to fill in just the last day of each month; if I use a `PeriodIndex` to index my series I can also `s.resample('D', convention='start')` to have only the first observation filled in. However, I also would like options to fill every day in the month with the monthly value, and to fill every day with the daily average (the monthly value divided by the number of days in the month).

Note that basic backfill and forward fill would not be sufficient to fill every daily observation in the month with the monthly value. For example, if the monthly series runs from January to March but the February value is NaN, then a forward fill would carry the January values into February, which is not desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
s.reindex(DatetimeIndex(start=s.index[0].replace(day=1), end=s.index[-1], freq='D'))
```

Comment: Thanks @eumiro, this answers the main part of the question. If you also have any ideas on the last part of the question that would be great as well.

Comment: you can fill the resampled series sr as following: sr.groupby(sr.index.month).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='backfill'))

Comment: Thanks @Walter. Using your guidance, I was also able to implement the daily average I mentioned: sr.groupby(sr.index.month).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='backfill')/len(x))

Comment: I don't think you need the groupby here if you use resample, there is a `fill_method` parameter in `resample` that just fills the time bin.

Comment: @Chang She - I was able to use s.resample('D', fill_method='backfill') to fill in data, however, I couldn't figure out how to use resample to get data starting from 2012-01-01 as opposed to 2012-01-31.

Comment: ah ok, you're manually reindexing? gotcha. There is a github issue open to have a third convention for resampling called 'span' that does exactly what you need. Hopefully we'll get around to it in the next version (or if you want to make a PR that be even more awesome ;))